# Presentation is being dismissed because the display metrics have changed since it was created

Tags: java, android, presentation

I am facing error in dual screen POS system. Presentation view is not working in Android 7.1.2 Nougat.

Below one message shown in android logcat window:

**Presentation is being dismissed because the display metrics have changed since it was created.**

Also it is displayed same content in both side in dual POS screen. **Presentation** is already working in Android 6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and found out that it is being caused by incorrect changing the base context of the activity (in our case for localization purposes).

Try to find out an override of `attachBaseContext(newBase: Context)` method in your activities hierarchy and temporarily comment it. If it helps then you have to fix your implementation to avoid setting context with incorrect display configuration.